# Weird ruby string concat behaviour

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, performance

I have tested following code:

```
irb(main):038:0> a=".";b="10"
=> "10"
irb(main):039:0> a+=b
=> ".10"
irb(main):040:0> a<<b
=> ".1010"
```

So far so good. Now lets repeat this process:

```
irb(main):042:0> a+=b+="4"
=> ".104"
irb(main):044:0> a
=> ".104"
irb(main):043:0> b
=> "104"
```

Good... now replace += with <<

```
irb(main):045:0> a=".";b="10"
=> "10"
irb(main):046:0> a<<b<<"4"
=> ".104"
irb(main):047:0> a
=> ".104"
irb(main):048:0> b
=> "10"
```

If << stands for += then why b is still 10 instead of 104?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<<` isn't the same as `+=`. `x += y` is basically an abbreviation for `x = x + y`. This creates a new string, and assigs it to `x`. For example:

```
> x = "hello"
> y = "world"
> old_x = x
> x += y
> x
"helloworld"
> old_x
"hello"
```

`<<` however actually modifies the string:

```
> x = "hello"
> y = "world"
> old_x = x
> x << y
> x
"helloworld"
> old_x
"helloworld"
```

That will explain the differences you are getting. Note that something like `a << b << "4"` is a pretty bad practice, as it is doing two modifications on the same line. It works this way because `<<` has left associativity, so it is the same as `a<<b;a<<"4"`. This would append `b` onto `a`, then "4" onto `a`.

Comment: thanks!  second example is really good, but as soon as I assign new value to the x (x="new") old_x doesnt get updated, even when I do the x << "old" after the x="new"

Comment: What `x = "new"` does is create a new string `"new"`,and assign `x` to it. It doesn't change the value of the string `x` used to be assigned to. That is why `old_x` doesn't change, since it still is assigned to the old string.

Answer (score 0):

> If << stands for += then why b is still 10 instead of 104?

`<<` *doesn't* "stand for" `+=`. They're different operators that do different things.

```
a << b << c
```

Is the same as

```
a << b
a << c
```

`<<` modifies the string and returns it, so the sub expression `(a << b)` first evaluates to `a` and then `a << c` continues to append to `a` without modifying `b`.

On the other hand:

```
a += b += c
```

is the same as

```
b = b + c
a = a + b
```

Answer (score -4):

> If << stands for += then why b is[sic] still 10 instead of 104?

Because, when the condition is false, the whole sentence is true regardless of what the conclusion is.

```
P     Q     If P then Q
false false true
false true  true
true  false false
true  true  true
```

Comment: This is not correct.  It's because of the nature of the operators involved.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Which part is not correct? Not clear what you mean.

Comment: "<<" does not stand ford "+=".  Your answer implies that you agree with that statement.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Which part is not correct? Not clear what you mean.

Comment: Shift operators and += operators are in no way equivalent.